# Speeding up an object in JS game after every 10 points

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to speed up an object in JS game x2 every 10 points.
In the game at the same time I use

```
let game = setInterval(draw,100);
```

Which technique should I try? I have been searching for a really long time yet trying to do it with changing the setInterval didn't work as it should (it accelerated over and over).

Would be really grateful for any advice (not looking for a ready code, just saying!).

Comment: I'd recommend not doing 2x, Whatever game you're making, it doesn't matter, 2x is just too insane. 1.2x or 1.3x is more like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to hang onto the `game` value returned from `setInterval`. You can use that to stop the current interval timer with `clearInterval()` and then start a new one with your new rate. Since you didn't post much code here's a contrived example that counts to 100 speeding up every 10 numbers:

```js
let i = 0
let speed = 1
let basespeed = 1000
function play() {
    console.log("play", i++)
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        speed *= 2
        clearInterval(int)
        if (i >= 100) return
        int = setInterval(play,basespeed/speed)
    }    
}

let int = setInterval(play, basespeed)
```